# How to solve Serverless split stack plugin failure around resourceConcurrency

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless, serverless-plugins, split-stacks

So I have a stack exceeding 500 resources and found out this [serverless plugin](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks) which splits stack according to the several configurations.

Below is my configuration for splitting the stack. Upon using the below configuration I was able to split the stacks in 2. with that I also got the warning `Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (TooManyRequestsException: Rate exceeded`

```
custom:
  splitStacks:
    nestedStackCount: 2 # Controls the number of created nested stacks
    perFunction: false
    perType: false
    perGroupFunction: true
```

To resolve the API rate limit I used resourceConcurrency property as below

```
custom:
  splitStacks:
    nestedStackCount: 2 # Controls the number of created nested stacks
    perFunction: false
    perType: false
    perGroupFunction: true
    resourceConcurrency: 20 # Controls how much resources are deployed in parallel. Disabled if absent.
```

Upon deployment, I received following error
`ServerlessError: The CloudFormation template is invalid: ValidationError: Circular dependency between resources: [GetAllUsersLambdaFunction,.....`

is there any workaround to resolve this issue? Is resourceConcurrency even in a working state?